# too much recursion when inserting data in mongodb - meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, recursion, meteor

I have a couple of templates with some copy in them. The copy is editable by the user and when the user edits and saves (by clicking a button) I insert the edited copy along with all HTML tags (for later, when I print the data out again) in a db.

When I log the data it works but as soon as I try and write it to the db I get a 'too much recursion' error and I don't understand why.

// Event

```
Template.editControls.events({
'click .save': function(e) {
  var target = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
  var targetContent = target.nextElementSibling;

  if(targetContent.isContentEditable) {
    var targetData = targetContent;
    var selectedCopy = Session.get('activeElement');

    ContentCollection.update(selectedCopy, {$set: {content: targetData}});

    targetContent.contentEditable = false;
  }
}
});
```

// Template

```
<section class="content" id="header">
    <ul class="inline-list">
        <li class="edit">edit</li>
        <li class="save">save</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="content__editable" contenteditable="false">
        <p>Header content I can change</p>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `var targetData = targetContent.textContent;` instead of `var targetData = targetContent;`?

Comment: It can happen if you have a prototype loop. Is your `targetData` linked via prototype to your `selectedCopy`?

Comment: @user3374348 - it works when I add textContent but that removes all my HTML tags. I need that when I insert it again on page load.

Comment: @Kyll - I don't have any prototype links

Comment: Try `.innerHTML` or `.outerHTML` instead of `.textContent`.

Comment: outerHTML is doing what I need without the error. Thanks.